# Java program won't run properly after compiling

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I am new in programming and making my first program using all resources I can found on internet. So I made Java with Maven Application using NetBeans 11.2. I finally made to the point when I complied my program and now I am stuck. I tried to run it from Command Prompt and issues begone. First I had to deal with `NoClassDefFoundError: AbsoluteLayout` issue. I had to fix it by changing Layout in whole project to `NullLayout`. After finally program started i got another error `NoClassDefFoundError: com/mchange/v2/c3p0/ComboPooledDataSource`. For several day I am trying to find answer and still no luck. Tried every suggested steps.

- Checked the pom.xml file - dependencies listed.
- Checked libraries in NetBeans - libraries included
- Reconfigured Maven for NetBeans.
- Clean and rebuild project numerous times with different option (just Build, clean and build, and sow on)

Looks like for some reason dependencies doesn't want to load.
Can anybody help me please.

Thank you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ews.ykotov</groupId>
    <artifactId>TechInfo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>unknown-jars-temp-repo</id>
            <name>A temporary repository created by NetBeans for libraries and jars it could not identify. Please replace the dependencies in this repository with correct ones and delete this repository.</name>
            <url>file:${project.basedir}/lib</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.18</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
                    <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>mchange-commons-java</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.5.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.swinglabs.swingx</groupId>
            <artifactId>swingx-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.5-1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.toedter</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcalendar</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.netbeans.external</groupId>
            <artifactId>AbsoluteLayout</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE112</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>13</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>13</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>techinfo1.MainPage</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Command Prompt Error:**
[image: Command Prompt Error]

Comment: add the jar that contains `ComboPooledDataSource` to your classpath.  Maven takes care of the building part.

Comment: Added to System Environment CLASSPATH still did not help.

Comment: try `java -cp ...jar`

Comment: Error: Could not find or load main class TechInfo-1.0.jar
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TechInfo-1.0.jar

Comment: program starts with java -jar

Comment: *Could not find or load main class TechInfo-1.0.jar* - so this is a different error, but the same way to solve

Comment: @Yuri, to run your code you need not only your own code, but also *all* the JARs which you defined as dependencies. You can use the `maven-dependency-plugin` to create lib directory holding all your dependency JARs. Then make sure to include that lib in your classpath using `java -cp "TechInfo.jar;lib/*" techinfo1.MainPage`

Comment: @Simon, i thought compiler suppose to do it for me (to put everything in one place) when i build the project. i guess I was wrong. Thank you I will try it tonight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Simon finally solved that issue and moving to next stage. I also had to modify my pom.xml's  file build section using this article  (https://crunchify.com/how-to-create-build-java-project-including-all-dependencies-using-maven-maven-resources-maven-dependency-maven-jar-plugin-tutorial/). Maybe somebody will find it helpful.